# Airbnb Airflow: Installing Airflow without pip

Tags: python, pip, airflow

Is there a way to install Airflow without pip?

I am trying to install Airflow on a offline computer that does not have pip. I have downloaded the packages from the internet but I am not sure how to run the installation without pip.

Does anybody knows how to run an installation with 'setup.py'?

Comment: python setup.py install

Comment: I am getting this error when I run this command:
ImportError: No module names setuptools
I believe that this module is part of pytho-pip

Comment: The solution might be to download all the dependencies then installing each one and finally running 'python setup.py install'

Comment: @CPME [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) is its own package, not part of `pip`. If you don't have a network connection, you'll need to get all of airflow's dependencies to the machine some other way before you'll be to install it.

Comment: One way to install Airflow off line is to download all the dependencies on a computer with internet connection using 'pip download airflow' and then copy and 'python setup.py install' in the offline machine. You will need python-dev and gcc-c++ as additional dependencies.

Comment: Easy way: you can create a virtual machine on a computer that has an internet connection, then install Airflow on it with pip. Now drop it on your offline machine and forward a port inside the VM if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
# /usr/bin/bash
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

If you get problems like the lack of `setuptools` you can install it (depending on your system, it usually a package. If you want to be sure to have everything download and later install the `python-devel` (sometimes also python-dev) package with your OS package manager) or you could use airflow via `docker`, you will build the image and then export it to the offline unit.

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixing it now.

Answer (score 1):

To install it without pip,

- download airflow zip from [git-repo](https://github.com/apache/airflow).
- unzip the contents and follow the instructions in the INSTALL file. (Steps inside create a virtualenv and then start the airflow installation)

These are the steps you will find in INSTALL file:

```
python -m my_env
source my_env/bin/activate    
# [required] by default one of Apache Airflow's dependencies pulls in a GPL
# library. Airflow will not install (and upgrade) without an explicit choice.
#
# To make sure not to install the GPL dependency:
#   export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
# In case you do not mind:
#   export AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes

# [required] building and installing
# by pip (preferred)
pip install .

# or directly
python setup.py install
```

Alternative, If you are facing any conflicts while installing through pip,

1. create a virtualenv
2. source-activate virtualenv
3. Follow steps from [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html) to install and configure it.

One way or the other you will have to use pip as there might be a number of modules you may have to download using pip. Creating a virtualenv here will help.